# How to override GWT obfuscated style for DataGrid header

Tags: css, gwt, datagrid, overriding

I'm trying to figure out how to override the dataGridHeader style defined in [DataGrid.css](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.css?r=10228)! GWT core.   The GWT style name is obfuscated with adler32 so I can't simply use .dataGridHeader in my css.  In my case I wish a simple change of white-space:normal.

I've seen may articles here about injecting css but they all appear to be class level rather than a sub style used within a component like DataGrid.

How do I override a header style used within a component like DataGrid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just like with any `ClientBundle` and `CssResource`: create an interface that extends `Datagrid.Resources` and overrides the `dataGridStyle` method with a `@Source` annotation pointing to your own CSS file (or possibly to both the original file and your own file, so they'll be combined together).

Doing it that way will override the style for *all* `DataGrid`s in your app though (it actually depends on which `CssResource` instance gets `ensureInjected()` first: the one from the original `DataGrid.Resources` or the one from your sub-interface): because you use the same return type (`DataGrid.Style`), the obfuscated class names will be the same.

If you want to change the style on a case-by-case basis then, in addition, declare an interface that extends `DataGrid.Style` and use that as the return type to your `dataGridStyle` override: because the obfuscated class name is based on both the interface fully-qualified name and the method name, your `DataGrid.Style` sub-interface will generate different obfuscated class names than the original `DataGrid.Style` interface.

Then of course, `GWT.create()` your `DataGrid.Resources` sub-interface and pass it as an argument to the `DataGrid` constructor.

See also http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6144

Comment: I was able to get your first suggestion to work but I couldn't do it with ensureInject ordering.  Either order would result in the original css being used.  Looking at DataGrid.java it looks like it always uses it's own GWT.create result.  Passing it to the constructor worked. ` public interface MyResources extends DataGrid.Resources {
     @Source({DataGrid.Style.DEFAULT_CSS,"DataGrid.css"})
  DataGrid.Style dataGridStyle();
 }
 static MyResources resources = GWT.create(MyResources.class);
`

Comment: The bit about using a different style on a case-by-case basis saved me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

Thanks Thomas.

Just to make it easier for the readers...

Create a new Interface

```
public interface GwtCssDataGridResources extends DataGrid.Resources {
      @Source({Style.DEFAULT_CSS, "gwtDataGrid.css"})
      Style dataGrid();
}
```

Use a static reference

```
public static final GwtCssDataGridResources gwtCssDataGridResources = GWT.create(GwtCssDataGridResources.class);

    static {
        gwtCssDataGridResources.dataGrid().ensureInjected();
    }
```

Finally create a new CSS file gwtDataGrid.css. Note that if you need to override a style, you have to use **!important** on each definition.

```
.dataGridHeader {
    color: #FF0000 !important;
}

.dataGridFirstColumnHeader {
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

.dataGridLastColumnHeader {
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

That's it