# How to remove text-shadow from column headers in GWT DataGrid?

Tags: java, css, gwt, datagrid

I have been trying to override the CSS used to define the default text-shadow from the GWT DataGrid column header. According to Google, the CSS is defined in DataGrid.css, but overriding the `.dataGridHeader` class defined therein, has no effect. In the CSS file, the default behavior is defined as:

```
.dataGridHeader {
 border-bottom: 2px solid #6f7277;
 padding: 3px 15px;
 text-align: left;
 color: #4b4a4a;
 text-shadow: #ddf 1px 1px 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Overriding this class in the module CSS has no effect.

Interestingly, I did discover elsewhere that other behavior can be successfully changed by overriding .x-grid3 CSS classes. For example, row height can be set as follows:

```
.myRowHeight .x-grid3-row { height: 30px; }
```

This is applied to the grid instance by calling the `.addStyleName()` method on the instance.

This suggests that the implementation of DataGrid is not using DataGrid.css after all, and the that Google's documentation is wrong. I am not familiar with the .x-grid3 CSS, so am not sure which class would be overridden to remove the text shadow.

By the way, I do understand the CSS injection route, but I would like to understand why the .x-grid3 override works for row height, and whether a different override will solve my problem.

Comment: Without an example to look at, I can't help you. Try using Firebug or Chrome's code inspector to figure out what rules are effecting your markup.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. The .x-grid3 solution was something I found here, so I was hoping someone familiar with that CSS class set might know the appropriate class to override within the set to achieve the desired behavior. Seems like Google is using a third party CSS class set inconsistent with their documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to override GWT obfuscated style for DataGrid header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877280/how-to-override-gwt-obfuscated-style-for-datagrid-header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you overriding this css ? Did you just add the `.dataGridHeader` class to your own css stylesheet ? 
Please have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10878147/405492) detailing how to properly override the css of a DataGrid. This is a recurring question that has already been answered multiple times here on SO.

Comment: Yes, as I indicated, I was aware of that approach and am doing that now. My question was more from a curiosity standpoint. It seems Google subverted a third party component in building their datagrid, and this explains why the .x-grid3-row CSS class work for the row height. Thanks.