# How to apply different css style to gwt datagrid widget in the same page?

Tags: css, gwt

I use this solution 
[How to override GWT obfuscated style for DataGrid header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877280/how-to-override-gwt-obfuscated-style-for-datagrid-header)
to override styles for a gwt datagrid widget and it works fine, great !

But now, I need to style 2 datagrid in the same page with 2 differents css styles.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the Q/A you linked to:

> If you want to change the style on a case-by-case basis then, in addition, declare an interface that extends `DataGrid.Style` and use that as the return type to your `dataGridStyle` override: because the obfuscated class name is based on both the interface fully-qualified name and the method name, your `DataGrid.Style` sub-interface will generate different obfuscated class names than the original `DataGrid.Style` interface.
>
> Then of course, `GWT.create()` your `DataGrid.Resources` sub-interface and pass it as an argument to the `DataGrid` constructor.
>
> See also https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6144

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Actually, the answer was in the linked answer already; copy/pasted here, and marked Q as duplicate.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your very quick answer. But as explained by AtanuCSE, it's not the same question and the answer is not directly in the previous Q/A. So I don't think it's a good thing to mark it as duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you use external CSS instead of CellTableResources. Then you can simply assign a class to each table and define the rules in your CSS files:

```
.table1 th {
  font-weight:400;
}
.table2 th {
  font-weight:700;
}
```

You can still do it if you use custom resources, but you will need to add `!important` to your CSS rules.

```
.table1 th {
  font-weight:400 !important;
}
```